# Websocket does not work over https, using socket io and redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am running an ubuntu Server with a simple Webpage so far. My websocket worked when the page was not secured(http) but since it is secured(https) the websocket does not work anymore.

This is my socket.js file in which I create the Server...

```
var app   = require('https').createServer(handler);
var io    = require('socket.io')(app);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

// class declaration
var Redis = require('ioredis');

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Redis InquirySent Channel
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Channel if an inquiry is sent,
 | an inquiry from a user to get permission to a specific stream
 |
 */
var redisInquirySent = new Redis();
redisInquirySent.psubscribe('inquiry-sent-channel-*');

redisInquirySent.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

// run server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server running!');
});
```

I get this error in my Google dev console / Network tab:

> ?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MBUPI17
>
> 127.0.0.1/socket.io

With following Headers:

> General: Request URL:
>
> https://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MBUPI17
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Request Headers: Provisional headers are shown Accept: */* Origin:
>
> https://testpage.com Referer: https://testpage.com/inquiry User-Agent:
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>
> like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36

Comment: For an https server, don't you need to pass an options first parameter to `https.createServer(options, handler)` that provides your certificates?  I don't see how you can have an https server without a certificate.  Have you tried just getting a plain web page from that https server to test if the server itself is running and working?  Does that work?

Comment: @jfriend00 previously I set it up to this `require('http').createServer(handler);` I just put the https in the question to tell that I tried using it using https, how excatly would a Connection look like

Comment: Did you look at the [doc for `https.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)?  It shows right there what you need.